# Закрывающий xml-тег в тексте textarea

Tags: html, xml, textarea

Нужно в textarea поместить xml-code.

Проблема с
`<Sphere radius='2.3'/>` и `<Material diffuseColor='1.0 0.0 0.0' />`
- на сайте это отображается с закрывающими тегами:  `<Sphere radius='2.3'></Sphere>` и `<Material diffuseColor='1.0 0.0 0.0'></Material>`

Как избавиться от этого?

```
 <textarea disabled cols='33' rows='20' id='text_code'>
            <X3D version='3.0'
            profile='Interchange'>
            <head><meta name='filename'
            content='RedSphereBlueBox.x3d'/></head>
              <Scene>
               <Transform>
                 <Shape>
                  <Sphere radius='2.3'/>
                 <Appearance> <Material
                     diffuseColor='1.0 0.0 0.0' />
                  </Appearance>
               </Shape>
             </Transform>
            </Scene>
            </X3D>
  </textarea>
```

[image: view xml-code in html]

Comment: А экранировать кто будет? `&lt;X3D` и так далее

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо :)